# Sometimes http headers do not pass to WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

Open webview below code.

```
func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let requestURL = URL(string: targetURL)
    var req = URLRequest(url: requestURL!)
    req.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.returnCacheDataElseLoad
    req.allHTTPHeaderFields = [
        "DEVICE-TYPE": "IOS"
    ];
    wkWebView.load(req)
}
```

Check http headers below, but sometimes deviceType is empty.

```
/**
 * Decides whether to allow or cancel a navigation.
 */
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    let deviceType = navigationAction.request.value(forHTTPHeaderField: "DEVICE-TYPE")
    if deviceType?.isEmpty ?? true { // <- Sometimes deviceType is empty, but not always.
        //
    }
    decisionHandler(.allow)
}
```

It occurs regardless of a specific OS and iphone version.
Is it bug of WKWebView?
Please help me.
swift version is 4.0.

Comment: Please post some description always before posting bunch of code

Comment: add description. thank you.

Comment: I am facing issue related header, where my header value gets update